# Setting up Android Emulator on WIN Server 2022

Tags: android, android-emulator, windows-server-2022

To show the functionality of an app we try to setup a Test Virtual Machine, which can be exported to an image for virtual box. It's like a playground environment.

The problem is that I can't seem to run any devices with the emulator. My preferred setup would be to launch the emulator with cmdline-tools in the command line, but I also tried it with Android Studio.

This is the output I get when launching the emulator from the command line:

`\Android\sdk\cmdline-tools\tools\bin>emulator -avd android34_nexusS INFO    | Android emulator version 33.1.24.0 (build_id 11237101) (CL:N/A) INFO    | Found systemPath \Android\sdk\system-images\android-34\google_apis\x86_64\ INFO    | Storing crashdata in: , detection is enabled for process: 7732 INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each individual line launch with the -log-nofilter flag. INFO    | Increasing RAM size to 2048MB INFO    | IPv4 server found: INFO    | Ignore IPv6 address:`

I also tried this with android version 33. The device I want to use is a legacy one called Nexus S.
With Android studio I get unknown error and the troubleshooting only advices me to file a bug against Android Studio.

My VM specs are the following:

- Processor: AMD EPYC 7542
- RAM: 8GB
- WIN Server 2022 64 Bit

I also tried to install the new Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver 2.1, but it did not work (this could be a different issue though)

After all this trial and error I wanted to ask if it is even possible to run the emulator or driver on this setup, because I could not find a definitive answer for this issue.